# Effecient method for structuring JSON data for querying

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, csv, data-structures

I'm trying to come up with an efficient method of storing static data in JSON so that it can be used in queries client-side.

Currently, this data consists of about 60 CSV files which each have approx. 2000-2200 entries each. I parse this data server-side and have a webservice that handles queries coming from the client. As mentioned, I'd like to be able to move this to the client side so that the web application could potentially work offline using the application cache.

A *small* sample of the data is below:

```
Battle Axe,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1
150,19EK,21EK,23EK,25EK,33ES,33ES,36ES,36ES,34ES,36ES,40ES,40ES,34ES,34ES,39ES,42ES,38ES,41ES,44ES,46ES
149,19ES,21ES,23ES,25ES,33ES,33ES,36ES,36ES,34ES,36ES,40ES,40ES,34ES,34ES,39ES,42ES,38ES,41ES,44ES,46ES
148,19EK,21EK,23EK,25EK,33ES,33ES,36ES,36ES,34ES,36ES,39ES,40ES,34ES,34ES,39ES,42ES,37ES,40ES,44ES,45ES
147,19ES,21ES,23ES,25ES,33ES,32ES,35ES,35ES,33ES,35ES,39ES,39ES,33ES,33ES,38ES,41ES,37ES,40ES,43ES,45ES
```

My original attempt at converting to JSON was based on the following:

- Each file was one JSON Object (lets call this object 'weapon')
- Each row in the file was another JSON object stored in an array under the    corresponding weapon object
- Each entry for a row was stored in a fixed length array under the row object
- All of the 'weapon' objects were stored in an array.

This meant I had one array that consisted of approx. 60 objects, which in turn had on average 100 objects stored within them. Each of these 100 objects had an array of 20 objects for each entry which consisted of the actual value and some additional meta data. As you can see, I am already at 120K objects... the resulting minified json string was 3mb. Small sample below:

```
var weapon = 
{
 Name: 'Broadsword',
 HitEntries: [ 
 {
    High: 150,
    Low: 150,
    Unmodified: false,
    Hits: [ { Hits: '12', Critical: 'CK', Fail: false},...,{ Hits: '1', Critical: '', Fail: false}]
 }, 
 ...
 {
    High: 50,
    Low: 47,
    Unmodified: false,
    Hits: [ { Hits: '3', Critical: '', Fail: false}] 
 }
 ]
}
```

An example of a query that will be run is below. It will be based on the sample data csv shown above:

- Battle Axe weapon is selected
- A value of 147 is selected for the roll (row)
- A value for 9 is selected for the armour type (column heading)

The result of the above should be **39ES** (cross reference between row and heading)

At this point I decided it was probably a good idea to get some advice before heading down this path. Any input is appreciated =)

Comment: Could Breeze be relevant to your interests? http://www.breezejs.com/home *Rich data for JavaScript apps is a Breeze*

Comment: I was looking into both Breeze and jLinq for the querying part, but at this stage, i was more interested in ensuring I have the most efficient data structure possible for this sort of data

Comment: Efficiency is a combination of data structure and query algorithm, I don't think you can do a particularly effective job of optimizing your data for querying unless you know how it's going to be queried. Also, how much optimization is enough? You won't know that unless you get some performance metrics. Might you be attempting to apply some premature optimization here?

Comment: Maybe. I guess there is no way I can get away from the size of the data for now. I'll give it a shot and see how I go

Answer (score 0):

You can make a few optimizations here:

1. Use WebSockets to stream data if possible
2. Convert the data to TypedArrays (blobs) - you'll end up dealing with something like a 10K file.
3. Use the index DB to query if needed